# SES email attachment in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Using Python 3.7, with a text file: 'sample.txt' deployed in lambda package and writing the logs of python program to this text file. Now, I'm trying to attach this text file and send email via aws-SES using mime libs. 
Note: Executing this whole program in a Lambda function.
Here's my code in lambda function:

```
import json, boto3
import logging as logger
import pathlib
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    #path = pathlib.Path().absolute()
    filename = ‘/tmp/sample.txt'
    logger.basicConfig(filename=filename, format='%(message)s',
                    level=logger.DEBUG, filemode='wt')
    #write these logs to text file
    logger.info(filename)
    logger.warning('233')
    logger.error('....')

    from = "abc@sample.com"
    to = "xyz@sample.com"
    region = "sample region"
    subject = "sample email"

    body = """<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <p>This email was sent for testing</p>
    </body>
    </html>
               """            
    ses = boto3.client('ses',region_name=region)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["From"] = from
    msg["To"] = to

    body_txt = MIMEText(body, "html")
    msg.attach(body_txt)
    fo= open(filename, 'rb')
    file_content =fo.read()
    attachment = MIMEApplication(file_content)
    fo.close()
    attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=filename)
    msg.attach(attachment)

    response = ses.send_raw_email(Source = from, Destinations = [to], RawMessage = {"Data": msg.as_string()})
```

**"errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/task/sample.txt'",**

1. Is this because /var/task will be deleted after executing the function?
2. saving text file in S3, is the only option?

Comment: Did you include sample.txt in your Lambda deployment package? If the file is not large, you can include the contents in your source file.

Comment: If I include in deployment package, its not able to write any logs in the text file.

Comment: I missed that part in your question. You have a catch-22. Until you close the file, you might not be able to access it in another part of your code ( I am not sure in this case). However, you are trying to write to a location where you do not have write permissions. Instead, specify the file as `/tmp/sample.txt`

Comment: Updated my code to close the file before attaching and modified path to /tmp/sample.txt, still same error: No such file or directory ‘/tmp/sample.txt’. Also updated my question that I’ve included txt file in deployment package. Thanks!

Comment: The logger created the file and has the file open. The point is that the file might not exist until it is closed by the logger. Try adding `logger.flush()` and `logger.close()`. Note: I have never tried closing the logger so that is why I am posting a comment. Refer to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html

Comment: As per the documentation, I’ve tried adding logger.handlers.flush() and logger.shutdown() and logs are not written to the text file.